# how to use a loop to jump at potions of equal distance between two numbers

Tags: java, oop, loops, for-loop

User inputs two integers and it returns how many spaces or evenly parts are between them,if the parts are every 7 numbers and user inputs 23 and 67 there will be a total of 6 spaces/parts which are 29,36,43,50,57,64.

numbers circled in green are the inputs, numbers circled in red are the numbers at the every-seven position that started at 23.

how can I return how many red circles will be and also how many numbers are not circled.

how can I make a variable to count the numbers circled in red and other to count the numbers that were not circled.

this is how it should work user inputs **23**(green) and **67**(green) and the integer **6** is returned if the parts are at the **every-7**(red) distance.

[image]

here I'm trying to return how many red circles will be.

```
public class met2 {


    int spaces(int firstnumber, int secondnumber){

        int spacein = 0;
        for(int i = firstnumber; i>secondnumber; i+=7){
        spacein = spacein + i;
        }

        return spacein;
        }


    public static void main(String args[]){

        met2 test = new met2();
        System.out.println(test.spaces(23,67));
    }

}
```

Also can it be done using only loops, and can it be done using only if statements.
What would be the simplest and most efficient approach to get the desired results?

Comment: The first jump is from 23 to 29, which is 6. After that its 7 (the last from 64 to 67 is 3), are there rules HOW the space between the 2 user inputs should be parted?

Comment: Have you tried using arithmetic, division in particular?

Comment: either way its correct counting 23 like is one jump or counting 24 as one jump, in this example I would like to have the 23 counted as one jump, but  counting 24 as one jump moves one position all the red circles, both approaches are welcome. I had posted the picture when I noticed my error that the first part is composed of 6 numbers but I left it for curiosity on the solution as well

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes but how to return multiple values in one method, the red cirlces, how many numbers where not circled, which are the numbers that were circled and which are the numbers that were not circles, all in one method. is it posible?

Comment: @hamena314 64 to 67, 64 is red circled because 57 is red circled and 57+ 7 is 64.  67 is the input number and there is not a separation space of 7 numbers between 64 and 67. the first input 23 counts as one so it only needs to count 6 more, after that all are seven to seven.

Comment: @adrian: How you return them and how you calculate them are two distinct issues; you only asked about the first, not the second.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with your approach you should change the loop condition

```
for(int i = firstnumber; i>secondnumber; i+=7){
```

into

```
for(int i = firstnumber; i<=secondnumber; i+=7){
```

But a better approach to get the number of red squares would probably be something like this

```
(secondNumber - firstNumber + 1) / 7
```

Edit:
Reading the comments I suggest the following:

Create a new class that has two variables - numberOfRedSquares and numberOfWhiteSquares. From the method make a new object of the class, set numberOfRedSquares equal to

```
(secondNumber - firstNumber + 1) / 7
```

and set numberOfWhiteSquares equal to

```
secondNumber - firstNumber - numberOfRedSquares
```

But if you also need the numbers that were circled and numbers that weren't you should stick to using loop.

Comment: If the user entered `23` and `29`, `29` would be circled in red, yet `numberOfRedSquares` would be 0.

Comment: oh right, he started counting from the number entered. Just add 1 then.